# Which free IDE for C++ with easy GUI Development Environment (Windows) can be recommended

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, ide, rad

I would like to develop GUI Windows Applications (not Console, but Forms and Buttons) with C++ on Windows without using .NET. At the moment I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 C++ Express" and as you know it contains no "Form Editor" or RAD Tool for forms and buttons. What free tool I would use, which has such options? Assuming I'm having no money for Borland or Books and my knowledge is not very big (just started yet), where I would find free information and free tools to code Windows GUI Applications?

I found Code::Blocks, but it's for a newbie a very complicated free IDE with possibly some bugs and it contains a compiler which wasn't even able to start a two-liner example console application without being previously right configured, so I gave up on it (it was said that it can easily build a GUI).
I found wxWidgets, installed it, installed it even with the use of the Windows Installer WxPack, but couldn't get it working and found no working example codes or instructions to make it work.

I didn't understand why wxWidgets needs any "Sizers" to design a simple form, I downloaded the wxFormDesigner, but it wouldn't compile anyway.

I do not need "wxWidgets's" crossplattform feature, because I plan to code ONLY for windows.
wxWidgets seems to complicated to setup for a beginner and even the design is very unclear to handle, I don't know what "sizers" this wxWidgets always mourning about.

So I wonder if someone knows something better, something ready to use with C++ - SETUP and GO!
Any IDE with integrated RAD Editor and event handling (C# alike, but not .NET).

I answer now myself (since this topic got anyway closed):
The best commercial C++ RAD Tool with non-buggy Windows Compiler is: Embarcadero C++ RAD Builder.
The best freeware C++ RAD Tool with non-buggy Windows Compiler is: Ultimate++. It compiles
the framework within the C++ executable (no external DLL's and Setups needed), synthax is
self-explaining, no bugs, fast, small executable size and a RAD editor exists also.
Ultimate++ uses also QT, but it compiles it inside.

As for QT itself: Yes there exists also a very good hidden Setup for Windows, but it has 
dependencies and is not easy to use for a beginner.
What for a full new framework QT with dependencies which is not ready to use.

Comment: Why don't you want do use .NET? I think you'll have to go with MFC... but they arent available on Express :/

Comment: [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) is nice.

Comment: imho C++ is not the right tool for rapid gui development, especially for beginners. You might want to write the gui in another platform like .NET an add a C++ backend. If you really want to write C++ GUI have a look at QtCreator

Comment: Code::Blocks isn't a compiler at all, and while it does have bugs (like all nontrivial programs) it's completely usable. I'd say the problem is with you. "Sizers" in wxWidget are what "Layout Manager"s are in other GUI libraries. It's common across the board, except in low level GUI libraries.

Comment: Maybe you should get up to date somehow.. I think the days one would 'surely' pick Borland over VS are over. Not sure though. But coding for 95? Really? An OS nearly 20years old? Also your reasons why you do not want to use .Net do not make alot of sense.

Comment: .net is indeed pre-installed on XP. And Vista. And Windows 7. And Windows 8. I don't know what you mean when you say that you can't package up your minimum level .net into a setup program. That's just not true. GUI apps commonly written in C#/.net.

Comment: The .Net GUI Frameworks 'Win Forms' and WPF are included in VS Express products.

Comment: @feedwall No, it's not a compiler. You not understanding the difference between a compiler and an IDE is not my problem. If you downloaded a tarball you prolly downloaded the wrong thing - tarballs are archives. You probably downloaded a unix source distribution. Code::Blocks isn't my favorite IDE, but it does work and does not contain any viruses. Although reading your other comments here I'm convinced you're either a troll or otherwise extremely immature. You clearly don't have the slightest clue what you're doing and get aggressive when people tell you you're wrong.

Comment: @feedwall if you develop c++ gui apps, the libraries (yes, multiple installers needed, one for the CRT and one for Qt/WxWidgets/whatever you choose) it needs are also not preinstalled on any OS. Else they also run only on the developper's pc. You don't need 'research' to install .Net: if you develop an application, you should at least provide some installation docs saying where the user can find the needed lib, if any. Don't let them figure it out by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) can probably be the choice for you.

Comment: That is also my suggestion. Qt is a nice tool, but you have to spend a bit of time to learn it, as for every new framework. It's good investment

Comment: @feedwall Qt has bindings with loads of languages but it's native language is C++. You have asked a question and then ignored all the advice that has been offered to you. I'm not quite sure why you ask a question if you don't want to hear different opinions.

Comment: I didn't even know there is a binding for Java. Just got a good laugh.

Comment: you must be kidding right? http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/ it's the first link.

Comment: @feedwall We are trying to help. Why are you so aggressive? Nobody reading these comments will want to help you.